# How do I properly add a foreign key in active record?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to create some referential integrity across several tables, and am tripping over the placement of add foreign keys.  At best the statement is ignored, worst it throws an error.

```
class CreateCantons < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :cantons do |t|
  t.integer :canton_id
  t.string :canton_name

  t.timestamps null: false
end
end
end

class CreateResources < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :resources do |t|
  t.integer :resource_id
  t.string :resource_name
  t.integer :type_id
  t.integer :canton_id
  t.string :url
  t.string :address
  t.string :city
  t.string :state
  t.string :zip
  add_foreign_key :cantons, :canton_id #ignored
  add_foreign_key :types, :type_id #ignored

  t.timestamps null: false
end
end
end

class CreateResourceContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :resource_contacts do |t|
  t.integer :contact_id
  t.integer :resource_id
  add_foreign_key :resources, :resource_id
  add_foreign_key :contacts, :contact_id

  t.timestamps null: false
end
end
end
```

adding a t in front throws an error

```
t.add_foreign_key :contacts, :contact_id #error
```

How do I properly use this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to move the foreign_keys outside of the create table

```
class CreateResources < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :resources do |t|
      t.integer :resource_id
      t.string :resource_name
      t.integer :type_id
      t.integer :canton_id
      t.string :url
      t.string :address
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :zip

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_foreign_key :resources, :cantons
    add_foreign_key :resources, :types 

  end
end
```

see `http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key`

And also you need to tell it what tables you are adding it to.